Anti-war cartoon from the seventies, probably from eastern europe
I remember seeing a strange, quite simplistically drawn anti-war cartoon on TV, probably back in the mid-seventies. I don't recall the plot, but a significant part was that the army was produced by some sort of factory, which took in all kinds of various personalities at one end, and out came all identical-looking soldiers - one of the jokes was that a rubber ball was put through, and also came out looking as a soldier, but bounced around like a ball.
It might well be an eastern european film, quite possibly czechoslovak or hungarian, although it could be a trans-european coproduction. I am quite certain I have seen it multiple times, on german and probably also danish TV at the time.
I would like to know more about this film (and see it again), so I hope someone can help identify it.

It turns out I was wrong about it being from eastern Europe, in fact it was German, which explains it being shown on German TV. It is called "Konferenz der Tiere", and is from 1969. Here is a link to IMDB - the German Wikipedia also has an article.
The movie is apparently base on a well-known story by Erich Kästner, and is also the first German full-length animated movie in color.
